# Why do these two seemingly equivalent scripts take significantly different times to run?

Tags: python-2.7, time

I was doing some experiments in the interpreter and at some point I had to load a huge line-separated file and concat its line together. I first tried this:

```
strand = ['', '']
for i in range(1, 3):
    for line in open('chr2_strand_' +str(i) + '.fa').readlines()[1:]:
        strand[i] += line.strip()
```

Which was still running when I killed it after a few minutes. Next I tried this:

```
strand = ['', '']
for i in range(1, 3):
    s = ''
    for line in open('chr2_strand_' +str(i) + '.fa').readlines()[1:]:
        s += line.strip()
    strand[i - 1] = s
```

Which took less than a minute to run.

There are two files being read in the script and both are nearly 300MB each with each line having a 100 characters.

The difference is in directly updating the `strand` array rather than assigning the final concatenated result to it. I don't understand why this should affect the runtime as the array's size remains constant (two references to strings) which means it doesn't need to be relocated.

Python version is `Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18)`.

Any ideas?